# How to edit documents from PHP app on client with native Windows apps?

Tags: javascript, php, html, linux, windows

**Current situation**

We have web app for document management programmed with `html`, `php` and `JavaScript` hosted on a `centos` vm. One usecase is that users are asked to check new documents content. Often they prefer to do the annotations in the document. Currently they need to download them, edit them with native Windows apps on their client and upload them again. Documents can be PDF, MS Office or special CAD formats.

**Preferred situation**

We would like to eliminate/hide the down- and uploading for the user. The editing should still happen with the native Windows apps on the client of the user. Web editors like for example `PHPWord` are no solution for us as there are to many special document types. To the user it should appear as no difference whether the document is opened from the local file system or the web app.

**Question**

With which technology can documents from the PHP web app be edited on the users client with their native Windows apps?

**Brainstorming**

Is it possible to use `JavaScript` to save a temporary copy of the documents on the client of the user? Do we need a browser plugin? Do we need a native app to support the process?

Comment: _“Is it possible to use javascript to save a temporary copy of the documents on the client of the user?”_ - not with normal JS running in the context of a website; resp. at most, of course, in the form of a download dialog. _“We would like to eliminate/hide the down- and uploading for the user.”_ - then put the files on a shared network location that all clients have access to, or something like that maybe …?

Comment: Shared network location is no solution because the web app is accessible from the internet and we would like to prevent to use something like SharePoint. Further we need to trigger the web app when the document is edited. Thx for your idea anyway.